# gmmktime and mktime give me the same number

Tags: php, timezone, timestamp, timestamp-with-timezone

My PHP timezone is 'Asia/Tehran' so I would not expect gmmktime give me the same result as mktime.

> php info:
>
> Default timezone  Asia/Tehran

However when I type in my php console:

```
echo date('jS F Y h:i:s A (T)', mktime());
```

3rd September 2013 **11:23**:10 AM (IRDT)

```
echo date('jS F Y h:i:s A (T)', gmmktime());
```

3rd September 2013 **11:23**:16 AM (IRDT)

While I expect 3.5 or 4.5 hours time difference. Am I making a mistake somewhere?

Comment: you should be using `gmdate` and `date`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to give Argumente inside of **gmmktime()**. Your mistake is, understand first `mktime() vs gmmktime()`. see [this link](http://php.net/manual/de/function.gmmktime.php).

And The workaround is simple, use **[gmdate()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gmdate.php)** function to display dates created with `gmmktime()`.

```
<?php
  $inputDate = gmmktime(0,0,0,2,7,2012);
  echo gmdate("M d Y H:i:s O", $inputDate);
  // Feb 07 2012 00:00:00 +0000
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My aim was to generate UTC/GMT timestamp from now to compare with a timestamp in mysql via `FROM_UNIXTIME`. I'm confused of deciding which of my code to change: `gmmktime` in php or `FROM_UNIXTIME` in mysql ...